# If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has the property that $f'(x)<-1$ for all $x<1$ and $f'(x)>3$ for all $x>1$. Then $f'(1)$ does not exist?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has the property that $f'(x)<-1$ for all $x<1$ and $f'(x)>3$ for all $x>1$. Then $f'(1)$ does not exist? I think this statement is true, but haven't found a rigorous proof for it.

Comment: Do you know about [accepting answer?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) So far you have not accepted any answer to your questions. You may want going over your questions and seeing if some provided answers are worth accepting.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that it's differentiable at $1$, then:

$$\begin{array}{ll}
f'(1)=\lim_{x\to1^-} \frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1} &= \lim_{x\to1^-} f'(c_x)<-1\hspace{3cm} & c_x\in[x,1] \\
f'(1)=\lim_{x\to1^+} \frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1} &= \lim_{x\to1^+} f'(c_x)>3\hspace{3cm} & c_x\in[1,x] \\
\end{array}
$$
Since this is impossible, the function isn't differentiable at $1$.

$c_x$ exists by [The mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)

Comment: @user46944 Done. Thanks for the feedback.